# C++: Tic Tac Toe Computer Random Moves

Tags: c++, random, tic-tac-toe

I need help with my tic tac toe, because I am stuck at this one.
The random moves that the computer makes will overwrite the old ones, and I am not sure how to fix this.

```
if (computer == 1)  //computer = 1, means it's computer's turn
{
    i = rand() % 3;
    j = rand() % 3;
    if(board[i][j] !='X' && board[i][j] != '0')
    {
        board[i][j] = '0';
        computer--;  // computer = 0, means it's the player's turn
    }   
}
```

My 2D array is this one:

```
char board[3][3] = 
{{'1', '2', '3'}, 
{'4', '5', '6'}, 
{'7', '8', '9'}};
```

Comment: `computer--;  // computer = 0, means it's the player's turn` - Why not just: `computer = 0; // means it's the player's turn`

Comment: What's the type of `computer`?

Comment: Or a boolean? `computers_turn = true`. Readability++.

Comment: What happens when the condition inside the inner `if` is false?

Comment: everytime the number generated is  board[i][j] =='X' && board[i][j] == '0' the program will go in to an infinite loop, instead of going back and search for another random number.

Comment: There is no loop in the posted code. No one here is able to tell why an invisible loop is infinite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
    if (computer == 1)  //computer = 1, means it's computer's turn
        {
            bool found = false;
            while (found == false)
            {
            i = rand() % 3;
            j = rand() % 3;
            if(board[i][j] !='X' && board[i][j] != '0')
            {

            board[i][j] = '0';
            found = true;
            computer--;  // computer = 0, means it's the player's turn
            }

            }
```